# Why a specific page for newrelic.com doesn't log you in but rpm.newrelic.com does?

Tags: cookies, newrelic

After logging in into newrelic.com and asking it to remember you for 2 weeks, if you close and open the browser a puzzling situation occurs in which if you go to a specific URL like:

https://rpm.newrelic.com/accounts/56519/applications/800155

New Relic asks you to log in, but if you go to:

https://rpm.newrelic.com

you are logged in. Is this just how New Relic reacts to requests or is there something about cookies that makes it work that way?

I have a bookmark folder in Chrome with a bunch of those long URLs that I open in various tabs all together and it's annoying that they are not directly logged in.

PS: I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask, I'm happy to close and ask somewhere else.

Comment: It would be better to check with the New Relic Community forums (http://discuss.newrelic.com) or checking with New Relic Support for this type of question.

Comment: @NR_Jacob I also asked in the new relics forums, where I got as many answers as her (https://discuss.newrelic.com/t/why-doesnt-new-relic-log-me-in-with-specific-urls-but-it-does-with-the-root-one/16210). I asked here in case there was something about cookies that I was missing.